# Cannot remove grid and axis from pie chart using theme_ft_rc from hrbrthemes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, pie-chart

I'm having a theme issue in R when trying to make a pie chart. I have looked all over for solutions to this but nothing seems to help. I'm not exactly an expert either, so I have exhausted my skills. Hopefully there's an easy solution I'm missing here.

I want to use theme_ft_rc() from hrbrthemes for a pie chart, but I cannot get rid of the tick markers and y axis labels no matter what. This method works for all of the standard ggplot2 themes but does not seem to work for theme_ft_rc() or any of the themes from hrbrthemes. Here's a code example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

Test <- data.frame(name = c("Hello","World"), value = as.numeric("1","1"))

ggplot(Test, aes(x=NA, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  labs(caption = "Caption") +
  labs(x="",y="") +
  theme_ft_rc() +
  theme(axis.line = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

[Here's an image of the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw7Bw.png) How do I get rid of the axis, tick marks, floating "NA", and numbers? Previously setting axis.line, axis.text, etc to element_blank() would do this, but for some reason it is not working here.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this package overrule **ggplot2** default, a solution would be:

- Change `NA` to a blank space
- Use `theme_ft_rc` arguments

### Like this:

```
Test <- data.frame(name = c("Hello","World"), value = as.numeric("1","1"))

Test %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  labs(caption = "Caption") +
  labs(x="",y="") +
  theme_ft_rc(grid = F)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, the numbers are still there when I run this code. Is there a way to overrun theme_ft_rc to get rid of them as well?

Comment: Try `theme_ft_rc(grid = F,axis_text_size = F)`, but my recommendation would be not to use this package and customize your theme, using only ggplot2